# Aviation history. My dad PM of F-14

Tags: aviation-history

My father was Prog mgr of F14. Where can I sell or donate his memorabilia or where is site to help?

Comment: You can sell almost anything on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com). If what you have is seriously collectible then the big auction houses (Christie's, Sotheby's) might have an appropriate event where you could list it. This isn't really an aviation question, though.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you contact the Naval Aviation Museum at NAS Pensacola FL to discuss donating or loaning them.  That way his legacy can live on with a plaque stating "Items in this display donated by ___, NAVAIR Program Manager F-14 Tomcat Systems, 1972 - 1986". (or something similar)